# How to convert DateTime to DateTimeOffset for ambiguous local timestamps?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, datetimeoffset

I need to write data into a SQL Server table in my C# application. The data type of the timestamp field in the table is DateTimeOffset and in my application I can get the timestamp as either local DateTime object or UTC DateTime object. How can I convert those timestamps to DateTimeOffset and include the offset information of the local timezone? By that I mean that I do not want DateTimeOffset objects with UTC time and offset 0:00 but instead I want to always include the offset of the local timezone.

Edit: It seems like simply creating a DateTimeOffset object from the local timestamp like `new DateTimeOffset(value.Timestamp.LocalTime)` works perfectly fine but I do not understand how this is possible when a DST time change happens. When I print out both local DateTime objects, before and after the DST change, I get this result:

```
// Before DST change
value.Timestamp.LocalTime
{25.10.2020 02:00:00}
    Date: {25.10.2020 00:00:00}
    Day: 25
    DayOfWeek: Sunday
    DayOfYear: 299
    Hour: 2
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 10
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 637391880000000000
    TimeOfDay: {02:00:00}
    Year: 2020

// After DST change
value.Timestamp.LocalTime
{25.10.2020 02:00:00}
    Date: {25.10.2020 00:00:00}
    Day: 25
    DayOfWeek: Sunday
    DayOfYear: 299
    Hour: 2
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 10
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 637391880000000000
    TimeOfDay: {02:00:00}
    Year: 2020
```

These DateTime objects seem to be identical, but when I look at the data written to the database I see this:
[image: Converted DateTime before and after DST change]

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean like `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I think so. What I mean is that for example for the current time I want to get a DateTimeOffset "2020-10-30 09:00:00.0000000 +01:00" and not "2020-10-30 08:00:00.0000000 +00:00".

Comment: what do you mean by `local timezone`? it is the timezone of web server, browser or sql server?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The timezone of the system where my application is running on, not where the database is located. There is no web server or browser because I am not working on a web application.